# Latest kernel update killed my nfs-service?

Tags: server, nfs

I got a storage server running 18.10, and today an kernel update came along and since it is running an AMD CPU I thought it would do me good.
Installation went perfect but after that the other servers getting its storage from said server were not able to connect.
The error message is:

```
Job for nfs-server.service canceled.
```

Heres my status of nfs-kernel-service:

```
 nfs-server.service - NFS server and services
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nfs-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2019-05-17 06:54:19 UTC; 2min 16s ago
  Process: 2732 ExecStopPost=/usr/sbin/exportfs -f (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2731 ExecStopPost=/usr/sbin/exportfs -au (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2729 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/exportfs -r (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)    
May 17 06:54:19 filestorage systemd[1]: Starting NFS server and services...
May 17 06:54:19 filestorage exportfs[2729]: exportfs: Failed to stat /mnt/storage/proxmox: No such file or directory
May 17 06:54:19 filestorage exportfs[2729]: exportfs: Failed to stat /mnt/storage/mainstorage: No such file or directory
May 17 06:54:19 filestorage systemd[1]: nfs-server.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
May 17 06:54:19 filestorage systemd[1]: nfs-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 17 06:54:19 filestorage systemd[1]: Stopped NFS server and services.
```

What can I do to save this?

Comment: From the status information, the problem is not your NFS server but rather the missing directories the server tries to export. `exportfs: Failed to stat /mnt/storage/proxmox: No such file or directory`  and `exportfs: Failed to stat /mnt/storage/mainstorage: No such file or directory`. Check your mounts, then restart the NFS server.

Comment: That was the problem for some reason I forgot to add that the raid-array to auto-mount at boot.